# Remove a file from usr/include?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I am trying to run a program from command line in ubuntu and I have a directory that is in the usr/include/ directory that I need to remove so that it will run.  How can I do this from command line?

Comment: rm -rf /path/to/dir/that/you/want/removed

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `/usr/include` should not be modified by a normal user/application.

Comment: Yeah, what @mensi said.  If you don't want the package that installed that directory, use the package manager to remove the package.

Comment: DO NOT run `rm -rf` if you do not understand what it does!

Comment: i had just accidentally dragged a folder in there an then needed to remove it, it didn't have anything important just a few jpg files but I needed to add a folder with the same name there

Comment: Dear clifgray. If you can accidentally drag a folder into /usr/include, there's a whole lot more you should worry about. Because you are running with root privileges. Even if you are the only user on the system, you should not do that.

Comment: @KlaasvanGend I just removed root privileges and got it all cleaned up.  thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rm -r /usr/include/...
```

Just use that. But if you need to do that, there is something wrong with your program. If a package installed the directory, use:

```
sudo apt-get purge package-name
```

All in all, the directories directly under `/usr` are under the charge of the package manager, and if you want to do things without that, use the `/usr/local` dir. Changing other programs resources is a bad idea. Also, don't run anything you don't have to with `sudo`. That will end badly. And what program would require the removal of a dir in `/usr/include`?